# Best way to compare - Using Sorting or adding to Set

Tags: java, sorting, hashset

I have two Strings like

```
 String one = "one, two, three, four";
    String two ="two,nine,ten";
```

Now, if any of the numbers two / nine / ten is present in the first string, I need to return true.

And, I  Split both strings . splitOne[], splitTwo[] are present now.

Now, one way will be to compare each and every element more like a bubble sort. 
This will give me a complexity of O(n^2).
Will adding the elements to a HashSet get me better complexity ?
For adding to set, I need to iterate through both lists and add each element.
Which of these will  require lesser time ? Is there any significant difference ?

Comment: I'd recommend coding something and measuring it.  That'll be far more authoritative than an answer here.  For this trivial problem, I think anything will do.  It's not a difficult problem.  Bubble sort and inefficient algorithms can be fine as long as N is small.

Comment: How big are your String one and two going to be? Will one string be immutable and the second one change, or will both strings change for several requests? Do you need the fastest algorithm, or do you prefer simple and easy to understand code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It really depends on your use-case.

There is no point in trying to sort it yourself. There are much more efficient methods available, one of which is, obviously, using a `HashSet`.

If you really are working with up to around 30 words then `HashSet` is certainly your way to go. However, as the number of strings gets bigger you are going to start running into space problems. For a start `String.split` will eat huge amounts of memory when you get into the thousands of strings, let alone the `HashSet`.

If you wish to avoid using database then there are solutions such as a [Bloom Filter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloom_filter).

At the extreme end you would probably want to use a database of some sort.

Answer (score 2):

Lets say the no. of elements in the first set is N and the no. of elements in the second set is M.

Using a hashset will require O(N+M) as O(N) used for adding while O(M) is use for checking. (Assuming comparisons are O(1))

The 'bubble sort' way will take O(NM).

Theoretically, I think O(N+M) with a hashset will be faster in complexity. However, the constant factor of a hashset should be higher and hence you might not see any improvement for lower values of N and M.

Alternatively, since you are dealing with strings, comparison between strings aren't O(1). You can create a trie using the first set, taking O(A) time, where A is the number of characters in the first set. And then O(B) in total to traverse the trie to check, where O(B) is the number of characters in the second set. This might give you better performances than a HashSet as it is independent of any hashing function (and hence collision checking).

Comment: Thanks for the explanantion. Do you suggest using a tree ? or TreeSet. Can you please explain , " You can create a trie using the first set, taking O(A) time ". Should I create a tree and then traverse tree to compare

Comment: No. The TreeSet implementation is/uses a binary search tree. I was referring to a custom trie (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use HashMap and also can maintain the number occurences as value.
2. Or instead of spliting  strings, Split one string and conpare till the source String exits in distination one.

   private boolean testArray(){

   ```
       String one = "one, two, three,four,nine,ten";
       String two ="two,nine,ten,11";

       String strTwo[] = two.split(",");

       for (String string : strTwo) {
           if(!one.contains(string)) return false;
       }
       return true;
   }
   ```